# Lectura de archivos en c

Tags: c, archivo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct pila{
   int clave;
   char nombre[50];
   float salario;
   struct pila *psig;
}pila;

pila *pmaestro;
pila *NuevoElem();
void push(int clave,char nombre[],float salario);
void imprimir(pila *);

int main()
{
    char nmbre[50];
    int clve;
    float slrio;
    FILE *f1;
    f1=fopen("listas.txt","r");
    if(f1!=NULL){
            // ********
            while(!feof(f1)){
                fscanf(f1,"%d,%s,%f",&clve,nmbre,&slrio);
                push(clve,nmbre,slrio);
            }
            // ********
    }else{
        printf("Error de apertura");
    }
    imprimir(pmaestro);
    fclose(f1);
 return 0;
}

void push(int clave,char nombre[],float salario)
{ pila *q = NuevoElem();
   q->psig = pmaestro;
   q->clave = clave;
   strcpy(q->nombre,nombre);
   q->salario = salario;
   pmaestro = q;
}

pila *NuevoElem()
{ pila *q = (pila *)malloc(sizeof(pila));
  if (q==NULL) { printf("Falta memoria"); exit(0);}
  return q;
}

void imprimir(pila *pmaestro)
{
   while(pmaestro!=NULL)
   {
      printf("%d\t%s\t%f", pmaestro->clave,pmaestro->nombre,pmaestro->salario);
      pmaestro = pmaestro->psig;
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Este código debe de leer un archivo que contiene una serie de claves, nombres y salarios. Al momento de querer leer el archivo, por algún motivo se cicla el while y no avanza de ahí. ¿Por qué se cicla?

Comment: ¿Qué formato tiene el archivo de entrada? ¿Cómo están separados los tres campos? ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de algunas de sus líneas?

Comment: en el fscanf tienes nmbre sin el &. puede ser eso? indicanos el archivo que utilizas, no vaya a ser que tengas alguna coma o algo que te rompa el formato y continue... O que lo tengas abierto con otro programa...

Comment: @Jakala El `nmbre` está bien sin `&` porque es un array. Aquí el problema es seguro el formato del archivo que no encaje con el formato del `scanf()`. Para empezar me parece raro tenerlos separados por comas, y en todo caso `%s` tragaría la coma como parte del nombre, a menos que hubiera un espacio delante de la coma, lo que también es muy raro. Además `%s` no admitiría nombres compuestos. Por eso es indispensable ver el formato del archivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que vi tenes 2 problemas en tu codigo. El primero es en el `fscanf()` en la cadena de formato. Vos indicaste `"%d,%s,%f"`, podría deducir que tu archivo `lista.txt`tiene formato del tipo `<Clave>,<Nombre>,<Salario>`, en caso de equivocarme, por favor indícame como es el formato correcto. El error aca esta que cuando lea el formato `%s`va a leer nombre y salario junto. Ya que la lectura se realiza hasta encontrar un espacio o un `'\n'`.

Si podes modificar el archivo de texto, simplemente agrégale, en vez de una coma, un espacio entre el campo de nombre y salario. Caso contrario te recomiendo cambiar de estrategia de lectura.

Algunas ideas que se me ocurren es usar fgets para obtener toda la linea del archivo (recorda que esta funcion captura el `'\n'` asi que tendras que removerlo de alguna manera e ir separando los campos.

Como segundo error esta en este fragmento de codigo

```
 while(!feof(f1)){
    fscanf(f1,"%d,%s %f",&clve,nmbre,&slrio);
    push(clve,nmbre,slrio);
 }
```

Si ubicas de esta forma el fscanf o cualquier metodo para leer el contenido del archivo vas a entrar 1 vez mas al while de lo debido. Te hago un ejemplo con los siguientes datos:

```
 1,Juan 107.50
 2,Ana 109.25
```

PD: en este caso asumí que se podía hacer la modificación explicada mas arriba de cambiar la `,` por un espacio.

En la primera etapa del bucle, tu indicador de registro activo apunta al registro de `Juan`, lees el contenido y lo almacenas en la pila. Como no es el fin del archivo, sigo entrando en el while (el indicador de registro sigue apuntado a `Juan`)

En la segunda etapa se lee el registro de `Ana` (el ultimo registro del archivo) y se inserta. Vuelve a evaluar la condición del while, devuelve `true`ya que el apuntador esta en el registro de `Ana` pero esto ya es un error ya que no hay mas registros para leer u almacenar y lo que estarás insertando en la pila es basura.

Esto lo solucionaria de la siguiente manera:

```
fscanf(f1, "%d,%s %f", &clve, nmbre, &slrio);
        while (!feof(f1)) {         
            push(clve, nmbre, slrio);
            fscanf(f1, "%d,%s %f", &clve, nmbre, &slrio);
        }
```

Cosa de ya leer el primer registro y almacenarlo en la lista (siempre y cuando haya mas de 1 registro). Y de esta manera evitas leer basura. O sino podrias agregar un if preguntando si es el fin del archivo y salir del bucle o como mas te guste.

Tambien encontre en la funcion mostrar, que no es un error, que te olvidaste el `\n` luego de mostrar el contenido de la pila. Para visualizar cada registro uno abajo del otro y no todo seguido.

Espero que te haya ayudado y si algo no se entendió o me falto explicar, házmelo saber.

Saludos